# Navigate back within same editor group in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I've two editor groups and when I go back `alt+LeftArrow` (`workbench.action.navigateBack`) it jumps between editor groups. I'd like to keep this navigation restricted to the current editor group. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

A setting was just added, should be in v1.65:

> Added a new setting `workbench.editor.navigationScope` that can be
> configured to `editorGroup` to limit navigation actions such as "Go
> back" and "Go forward" to the current active editor group.

- See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/45233#issuecomment-1037071113

`workbench.editor.navigationScope`: `editorGroup`